# How to get [(ngModel)] name in controller angular 4

Tags: angular

I want get [(ngModel)] name in .ts file when input is in active state(when I clicked in input type to write something).
I am able to access value of it in controller but I need to access name of it.
eg. I have code as follow

```
<input type="text" id="docno" class="form-control" (click)="focusFunction($event)" [(ngModel)]="docData.docNum" required>
```

from Above,

I need [(ngModel)] name i.e "docData.docNum" in .ts file.

Please help me to get name of [(ngModel)]. can I get name into event ?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Actually I have multiple input boxes in form. and I want to know which one is selected(I have to highlight particular selected input box also) and according to selected ngModal name I am assigning value from ts file.

Comment: In that case, you are probably doing it in the wrong way. This is a typical [xyproblem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) ,can you add the actual requirement in your question instead of the **attempted solution**?

Comment: He want the raw attribute value...

Think of $el angular service. It basically inject your element in your component. Or $view, I'm not sure which one, neither have I tested.

I'm typing from my phone and am formatting my machine.

Comment: Thanks..guys for your response.. I solved my problem following way..(click)="focusFunction('docNum', $event)"  and in focusFunction i get focusFunction(model, event) { self. docData[model] = self.Name; } and assigned value to selected ngModel which is in Name variable

Comment: the way you want to do it is most likely impossible 

a binding like ' [(ngModel)]="data.name" '

will get turned into javascript that looks like this :

jit___listener_4('ngModelChange',function SomeComponentNameIdentifier($event) {
       return (ctx.data.name = $event);
});

which means once its compiled there is no string containing the binding anywhere anymore

Answer (score 1):

Pass the second parameter in the clicked function as hard coded string with the model name.

Answer (score 0):

You can add (focus) function for getting the value on click.

```
    <input type="text" id="docno" class="form-control" (focus)="focusFunction($event)" [(ngModel)]="docData.docNum" required>
```

And listen it in the .ts file using below code:

```
    focusFunction(event){
    console.log(event.target.value); 
     }
```

or by simply writing

```
    focusFunction(event){
    console.log(this.docData.docNum); 
     }
```